# send custom object to reducer in "redux-api-middleware"

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-api-middleware

I am using [redux-api-middleware](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware).

My **Action** for fetching account data :

```
import { RSAA } from "redux-api-middleware";
import { API_ENDPOINT, AUTH_HEADERS } from "../util/constants";
import { ACCESS_TOKEN } from "../util";

export function getAccount(accountID) {
  return {
    [RSAA]: {
      endpoint: `${API_ENDPOINT}/api/Expense/GetAccount/${accountID}`,
      headers: {
        ...AUTH_HEADERS,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      },
      method: "GET",
      types: ["GET_ACCOUNT_REQUEST", "GET_ACCOUNT_RECEIVE", "GET_ACCOUNT_FAILURE"],
    },
  };
}
```

My **Reducer** :

```
import store from '../util/store';

const INITIAL_STATE = store.setInitialState({
  payload: null,
});

const getAccountReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_ACCOUNT_REQUEST":
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
      };
    case "GET_ACCOUNT_RECEIVE":
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        isSuccess: true,
        payload: action.payload,
      };
    case "GET_ACCOUNT_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        isSuccess: false,
        payload: action?.payload?.response,
      };
    default:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
  }
};

export default getAccountReducer;
```

Now, whenever API gives success response, It will go to "GET_ACCOUNT_RECEIVE".
I want to pass `"accountID"` (which I passed as a parameter in `getAccount` action) to `"GET_ACCOUNT_RECEIVE"` reducer. So that I will be able to create payload with key value pairs of different accounts.

```
{
  [accountID]: {...action.payload},
  [accountID]: {...action.payload},
  [accountID]: {...action.payload},
  [accountID]: {...action.payload},
}
```

How can I pass `"accountID"` to the  "GET_ACCOUNT_RECEIVE" reducer ?

Comment: Btw, even though the github contributers will tell you to ask stuff like this on SO - you will be helped quicker and by people who know the library well if you create a github issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware#meta is meant for what you have in mind:

```
export function getAccount(accountID) {
  return {
    [RSAA]: {
      endpoint: `${API_ENDPOINT}/api/Expense/GetAccount/${accountID}`,
      headers: {
        ...AUTH_HEADERS,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      },
      method: "GET",
      types: [
        "GET_ACCOUNT_REQUEST",
        {
          type: "GET_ACCOUNT_RECEIVE",
          meta: { accountID } // <----------------
        },
        "GET_ACCOUNT_FAILURE"
      ],
    },
  };
}
```

Not sure if it works exactly like that, but the middleware author(s) seem to have considered this use case. There should be an `action.meta` besides the payload available in the reducer.

Comment: It worked. I am getting what I want in `action.meta` in the reducer